# Need pdf annotation supports handwriting / online / inserting pages in the middle of the pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-editor

I need pdf annotation supports handwriting / online / inserting pages in the middle of the pdf.

kamihq does everything except does not let us insert pages in the middle of the pdf (you have to keep on doing split/merges with blank pages pdf which can get very annoying).

Are there any other suggestions ?

Comment: What OS/platform are you asking about?

Comment: It has to be online like the question mentions. I.e. synced across all your devices ?

Answer (score 0):

There is PDF Annotator: *Add notes & annotations to any PDF document - comments, corrections, signatures, highlighting, even photos, designs and drawings.*

It can  insert pages: https://www.pdfannotator.com/en/articles/page_manager_1

Comment: This one is not synced with all your devices. You have to manually keep transferring the file from device to device ?

Comment: It has no built-in sync, but you can combine it with Dropbox, which gives you free file syncing.